# Обработка OnChange на сервере

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Нужно в обработчик `onchange` у `select` сослаться на функцию, на сервере.
Реализовать это через `PageMethods` не получается.

Пример одного из `select`:

```html
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function onChangeSelect(){
PageMethods.updateLocSelect()
}
</script>
<select id = "Area" onchange="onChangeSelect()">
  <option id=0 value="NULL">
  </option>
  <option selected id=1>
    Площадка 1 
  </option>
  <option id=2>
    Площадка 2 
  </option>
</select>
```

А в CodeBehind страницы, на которой у меня этот `select` есть публичная функция `updateLocSelect()`. Но он её, кажется, даже не видит, так как Firefox в инспекторе выдаёт следующее:

> элемент не найден send:1:1 ReferenceError: PageMethods is not defined
>   onChangeSelect()  equip.aspx:221 onchange()

Вопрос: как правильно вообще использовать PageMethods (ссылка на подробный гайд, желательно, русский)? И есть ли альтернативы этому?

Comment: Используйте серверный элемент управления (`runat="server"`). Аналогичный вопрос: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626697/onchange-event-for-select-attribute

Comment: покажите объявление самого метода updateLocSelect. Альтернатива web methods (и вообще asp.net web forms) - asp.net mvc. в нем такие вещи делаются гораздо проще :)

Comment: @PashaPash     
Public Function updateLocSelect()
        updateLocSelect = "alert(""1"")"
End Function

Comment: @Ponio добавил runat="server" на select. Ничего не изменилось

Comment: а ссылку смотрели? про `PageMethods` тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313532/pagemethods-in-asp-net

Comment: @Ponio смотрел. dropdownlist вообще не смог корректно отобразить. по второй ссылке тоже посмотрел, только там ответ на с# написали, как я понял? почти всем условиям у меня удовлетворяет. находится в codebehind, публичная, EnablePageMethods включен. А что такое "The page method must have the System.Web.Services.WebMethod attribute. [WebMethod]" я не пойму. Что это за атрибут? И где его прописать на VB?)

Comment: например так: [<System.Web.Services.WebMethod(BufferResponse:=False)> _](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Пробовал так.     <System.Web.Services.WebMethod(BufferResponse:=False)>
    Public Shared Function updateLocSelect()
        updateLocSelect = "alert(""1"")"
    End Function.
Тот же результат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема, думаю, отчасти была в попытке задать обработчик onchange инлайном. Повесил это через js. 
В данном случае выбрал селектором все элементы select с классом JQuery4Loc и на событие change каждого из них повесил функцию ArrayLoc_changed.

```
function Page_Init(sender) {
                            var ArrayLoc = $('select.JQuery4Loc');
                            ArrayLoc.each(function (index, element) { $addHandler(element, 'change', ArrayLoc_changed); })

                      }
```

В функции ArrayLoc_changed вызываю PageMethod.ИмяФункции и передаю 3 параметра:

1. переменная, которую принимает моя функция на сервере;
2. js-функция на успешное завершение PageMethod;
3. js-функция на НЕуспешное завершение PageMethod.

   ```
    function ArrayLoc_changed(evt) {
                           var ArrayLoc2 = new Array

                           // заполнил массив ArrayLoc2

                           PageMethods.ChangeLocation(ArrayLoc2, ChangeLocation_Success, ChangeLocation_Failure);
                     }
   ```

В CodeBehind страницы пишу функцию ChangeLocation. И ряд условий, чтоб она работала (из [ссылки](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313532/pagemethods-in-asp-net) в комментарии под вопросом):

- Необходимо прописать атрибут "System.Web.Services.WebMethod()"  (в угловых скобках) перед объявлением функции
- Функция должна быть Public
- Функция должна быть Shared
- Атрибут EnablePageMethods тега asp:ScriptManager должен иметь значение True.

CodeBehind

```
            <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function ChangeLocation(ByVal array() As String)
    Dim arrayToReturn() As Array = Nothing
    'ваш код
    Return arrayToReturn
    End Function
```

И в завершении добавил функции ChangeLocation_Success, ChangeLocation_Failure на js.

```
function ChangeLocation_Success(results) {
                            if (results) {
                                // обработка результатов
                                }
                          else
                              alert("An unexpected error occurred"); 
                      }
                        function ChangeLocation_Failure(error) {
                            if (error) {
                              alert(error.get_message());
                          }
                          else
                              alert("An unexpeceted error occurred"); 
                        }
```